# Is the following set operation true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove the following or else find a counter example:

For all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, $$((A \cup B) − C) \cup (A \cap B) = ((A − B) \cup (B − A)) − C$$

For the life of me, I can't figure out if its true or not. I have tried drawing the Venn diagrams but I'm not too good with them and can't quite figure out if diagrams representing either side of above equation look alike.Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to let $C = \emptyset$, since it seems that's allowed. I'll assume here that $C = \emptyset$.

Just thinking about the right side, the set $(A - B) \cup (B - A)$ has a special name: it's the *symmetric difference* of $A$ and $B$. It's the set of everything that's in exactly one of $A$ or $B$. In particular, it doesn't contain anything in $A \cap B$.

But if you notice, the left side certainly contains everything in $A \cap B$, doesn't it? So, can you cook up a situation that takes advantage of this fact?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the Right set $((A-B)\cup (B-A)) - C$ nothing in $A\cap B$ is included. However such elements are obviously included in the left set, since they are one part of the union.

Thus any choice of sets A, B and C such that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ is a good answer.

Ex: $A={1,2}, B={2,3} C={4}$ or maybe if you want something simple $A=B=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$,
$B=\{2,3,4\}$ and
$C=\{0\}$
Then $$[(A\cup B)-C]\cup (A\cap B)=[\{1,2,3,4\}-\{0\}]\cup \{2,3\}$$
$$=\{1,2,3,4\}\cup \{2,3\}$$
$$=\{1,2,3,4\}$$

But $$[(A-B)\cup(B-A)]-C=[\{1\}\cup\{4\}]-\{0\}$$
$$=\{1,4\}-\{0\}$$
$$=\{1,4\}$$

So there's a counterexample.